# Turning off greed not working in this regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to run the following search (with . made to match newlines either by adding the /s flag in perl or replacing it with `\_.` in vim):

```
/<output_channels>.*(?=Story).*?<\/output_channels>/
```

However the ? isn't turning off greed as it normally does - can anyone explain why? For example, it matches the entire contents of the following file rather than just the first element:

```
<output_channels>
  <output_channel>RSS</output_channel>
  <output_channel>Story</output_channel> 
</output_channels>

<output_channels>
  <output_channel>RSS</output_channel>
</output_channels>
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: So, are you using Perl regex or vim's regex search/replace?

Comment: The RE you give uses a couple of elements that don't work in vim.  Not sure if you realize this or not.  Check [`:help perl-patterns`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#perl-patterns) for a list of differences.  What are you using to do the search?

Comment: @BoltClock Both/either. Ultimately I'll use perl but I find it quicker to text regexes in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your sample text into a vim buffer, and then executed the command

```
:%!perl -e '$text = join("", <STDIN>); $text =~ /<output_channels>.*(?=Story).*?<\/output_channels>/s; print $&;'
```

The result is just the first block of XML.  I think this is what you want?

Note that I escaped the `/` within the regex.  Other than this, it is the same one given in your question.

Also note that the equivalent vim RE would be (tested, works):

```
<output_channels>\_.*\(story\)\@=\_.\{-}<\/output_channels>
```

See [`:help perl-patterns`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#perl-patterns) for a rundown of the differences between perl and vim REs.

Further note that [parsing heirarchical markup with regexps has been known to reawaken ancient demons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth, your vim RE doesn't work - it'd be nice to know one I could use while testing in vim, but the perl RE is all I really need.

Comment: ...though can you explain why the following doesn't work as intended (to capture just the second <output_channels> element in my file) when I switch to a negative lookahead. I have a feeling its to do with the greediness of the first .* but when I switch this to .*? I get an operator. Is there a way to capture <output_channels> elements not containing 'Story' or am I better off using a tool other than regexps?

/<output_channels>\_.*\(story\)\@<!\_.\{-}<\/output_channels>/

Comment: @tog22: I just tested the vim RE and found that it works okay with both [`/`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/) and [`matchstr()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchstr()).  Note that in vim you don't need to (and mustn't) surround an RE with `/` characters; I just left those in to make it similar to the perl-ish version.  I've taken them out.

Comment: @tog22: If you want to match a string of text that does not contain a particular submatch, you have to use something like `((?!submatch).)*`.  I.E. you specify that each position does not match the thing you're avoiding.

Comment: @intuited Really appreciate your help, but I'm afraid you'll have to talk me through it more slowly. In what complete expression would I use `((?!submatch).)*` to find an `<output_channels>` element not containing 'submatch'? I tried `<output_channels>.*?((?!Story).)*?<\/output_channels>` but this matches both blocks...

Comment: @tog22: It would be much easier to use an XML parser to do this sort of thing.  I'm not sure what's available in perl, but I find that Python's `lxml` module is very good.  It mostly consists of bindings to a C library, so perl may have the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first `.*` in your regex is still greedy. You only added `?` after the second one.

Comment: But the look-ahead will cover that in this case `(?=Story)`